# Image with Checkbox instead of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have an association where a Vote has many Images, and I'd like this association to be checkboxes but instead of text have an image next to the checkbox instead of a text value the an example of the outputted HTML would look like:

```
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="vote_image_id_1" name="vote[image_id][]" type="checkbox" value="1"><img src="boat.png" alt="Big Boat"> <br />
```

Is this possible to do with simple form or will I need to write a custom field for this? If i have to write a custom field could someone recommend some good resources on making custom fields with simple form.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now, but I would do it more or less like this:

```
options = []
images.each do |image|
  options << [image.id, image_tag(image.path)]
end
f.collection_check_boxes :votes, options, :first, :last
```

Maybe you can extract the construction of the options array to a helper method.

I hope it helps :)